# Why is the return type of the assignment operator for a class typically a non-const (rather than a const) reference?

Tags: c++

Consider this example code;

```
class X
{
    private:
    int i;
    public:
    const X & operator = (int i_) { i = i_; return(*this); }
    const X & operator = (const X &x) { i = x.i; return(*this); }
};

X foo() { X x, y; return(x = y = 5); }
```

Would it somehow be better if the assignment operators returned X & rather than const X & ?

Comment: Is it typically const?

Comment: First of all, title of the question contradicts the question. Second, what is typical?

Comment: @SergeyA : I thought so at first, too. Then I realized that the code is an example of what OP thinks might be better (const), not what he's calling the "typical" case (non-const). It's just worded funny. The last sentence asks if C++/STL designers consider non-const better than const.

Comment: @manni66 I think it's typically non-const, for example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D

Comment: Yes, but as you see your question isn't clear for most readers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: There's nothing wrong with having a space there.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux oops about the returns,  but I personally prefer the space.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Retracted, thank you. I was certain that each operator was it's own keyword. It seems I was mistaken.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/1HLSPc

Comment: It would be better if the assignment operators returned `void`. This would reduce risk of unintended assignment in conditions as `if(x = y)` would yield and error.

Answer (score -2):

Well returned type should always be `X&`. Reasoning is - suppose you have two X a, b ànd you have one function.
void getdata().

You can call (a+b).getdata(). But if return type would be `const X&`, it couldn't be possible. Now suppose `getdata()` is `const`. Then still you can call (a+b).getdata. 
     So having `X&` instead of `const X&` gives you liberty to call `const` and non const both functions.